# Why don't the play/stop/etc buttons on my XBMC Android remote app work?

Tags: windows-7, android, remote-control, kodi

I've installed the official [XBMC](http://code.google.com/p/android-xbmcremote/) [Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.android.remote&hl=en) on my Android phone to communicate to my 
XBMC instance on our Windows 7 HTPC.

I can browse and select videos with no issues, and the video starts playing on the TV correctly, but once the video is playing the stop, etc, buttons that display at the bottom on the app on my phone does not work.  Why would they not work, but the actual selection of the video all work correctly?